# How to make Meteor React inline svg element click link to page without refresh whole page

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, svg, href

I need some guidance. First time here, so maybe some of the "terms" I'm using is unusual, please bear with me.

I am trying to achieve as what title said in JSX (using Meteor plafform). Currently if I use xlinkHref in svg, when I click the element, it will open the link but resulted in refreshing the whole page. While outside svg (using href), it will open the link without refreshing whole page. Code example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class App extends Component {

render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <svg>
            <a xlinkHref="/nextpage"> //clicking this will refresh whole page
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
            </a>
            <circle cx="150" cy="50" r="40" fill="yellow" />
        </svg>
        <a href="/nextpage">Click to Next Page</a> //clicking this will not refresh
    </div>
    )
}
```

Note that if I wrap the "a" tag outside svg tag, it will definitely work, but I just need the red circle to be clickable.

I have been thinking about breaking the circle elements into separate svg then wrap with "a" tag, but lets just say I am unable to do that, how can I still click an svg element to open link without refreshing whole page?

Edit: fixed some code typo

Answer (score 0):

You can add onclick event handler on your circles.

```
export default class App extends Component {

  onCircleClick(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Inside on circle click');
    window.location='/nextpage';
  }

 render() {
 return (
 <div>
   <h1> Testing svg tag </h1>
   <svg>
     <circle onClick= {this.onCircleClick} cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red"/>
     <circle onClick= {this.onCircleClick} cx="150" cy="50" r="40" fill="yellow" />
   </svg>
</div>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi. Your solution doesn't work on me. It will open the link but still refreshing the whole page. I've tested "onClick" attribute outside svg tag too, result same as above. It seems that the event.preventDefault() doesn't trigger?

Comment: I think you need to bind the click handler to the component as follows; `this.onCircleClick.bind(this)`.

Comment: Tried it too, adding bind(this) also does not work as I wanted. @tsega

Answer (score 0):

**With React Router**

By using browserHistory from React Router you will be able to open the link without refreshing the whole page.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';


export default class App extends Component {

  handleClick(link) {
    browserHistory.push(link);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <svg>
          <a onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, "/nextpage")}>
            <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="red" />
          </a>
        </svg>
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

**browserHistory** uses the HTML5 History API when available, and falls back to full refreshes otherwise. browserHistory requires additional configuration on the server side to serve up URLs, but is the generally preferred solution for modern web pages.

More about React Router's API:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#browserhistory

---

**With history.pushState()**

If you can't use React Router, you can still use HTML5's API pushstate to change the route: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

```
history.pushState(name, title, "nextpage");
```

Note that history is not compatible with old browser: http://caniuse.com/#search=history

---

**With a router for Meteor**

It should be able to use history.pushState(). If not the router should have the equivalent of pushState the same way React Router does.